# Can I save my desktop layout as a file?

Tags: 10.10, gnome-panel

I'm interested in playing with AWN and Docky, but have spent quite a bit of time getting my current layout (using native gnome panels) in a usable state. Is there any way to save the layout (i.e. which panels I have, what launchers - including custom - are on them, etc.) to a file so that if I end up not liking either AWN or Docky I can restore my original native settings without redoing it all manually?

I'm running Maverick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gnome panel configuration is stored at ~/.gconf/apps/panel, you just need to backup it up.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to back up ~/.gconf/desktop/* as well?

Comment: Not for panel changes, desktop contains other settings like the desktop background, etc. You can explore the conf settings using gconf editor, from the terminal run: gconf-editor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great script to do just that!  Check out this link:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/how-to-restore-default-gnome-panels-in-ubuntu/